# TCP connection refused when hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, tcpserver

I have a ASP.NET Core website that listens on 8801 port for normal HTTP request. This program also listens on the 8803 port for MQTT TCP connection.

If I run the progam with Kestrel directly on the server as below:

```
dotnet MyWebsite.dll   # runs the command on the server
```

I can connect the remote 8803 port with my client successfully. So if I understand it correctly :

1. The MQTT Server does work fine when using Kestrel.
2. The 8803 port is not banned by the firewall.
3. The MQTT TCP Server can accept connection from my client.

However, when hosting within IIS (in-process or out-of-process), the TCP server doesn't work any more:

logs when using MQTT.fx:

> 2020-08-06 14:14:03,864  INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      :
> onConnect 2020-08-06 14:14:03,865  INFO --- ScriptsController
> : Clear console. 2020-08-06 14:14:03,868  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel
> : MqttClient with ID MQTT_FX_Client assigned. 2020-08-06 14:14:08,100
> ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Error when connecting
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable to connect to
> server    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:94)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_181]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_181]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:84)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     ... 8 more 2020-08-06
> 14:14:08,102 ERROR --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Please verify
> your Settings (e.g. Broker Address, Broker Port & Client ID) and the
> user credentials! org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable
> to connect to server  at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:94)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:701)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_181]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> [?:1.8.0_181]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown
> Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
> ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
> org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:84)
> ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.0.jar:?]     ... 8 more 2020-08-06
> 14:14:08,111  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
> 2020-08-06 14:14:08,112 ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           :

Actually, I cann't connect to server:8803 with normal tcp client.

---

1. I'm using MQTTnet(3.0.11) + ASP.NET Core(2.1):

   ```
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseKestrel(opts => {
               opts.ListenAnyIP(8803, l => l.UseMqtt());
               opts.ListenAnyIP(8801);
           })
           .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
           {
               // ...
           })
           .UseStartup<Startup>();
   ```
2. The HTTP Website works fine (8801).
3. I can't connect to the MQTT Server (8803) when hosted within IIS.

So my question is : why it happens? How can I host the program with IIS ?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to create IIS binding for both 8803 and 8801?

Comment: https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet/issues/519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you could try to use another way to create the MSQT server, and make sure you have open the right port to allow access.

Startup.cs:

```
var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder() .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1883) .Build(); services .AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions) .AddMqttConnectionHandler() .AddConnections() .AddMqttTcpServerAdapter();
```